# How to manipulate (using manipulate pkg) ggplot2 with time-stamped axis?

Tags: r, datetime, plot, ggplot2, rstudio

I would like to produce an interactive plot (using the manipulate package which comes with RStudio) which has time as the x-axis. The user should be able to use sliders on this axis to change the x-limits of the plot, but I can't achieve this. Code reproducing the error is:

```
require(manipulate)  
df <- data.frame(time=seq(ISOdate(2000,1,1),by="month",length.out=100),y=rnorm(100))

# This would do a standard - non interactive - ggplot
#ggplot(df,aes(x=time,y=y))+  
#geom_line()+  
#scale_x_datetime(limits=c(min(time),max(time)))

# This tries to do the interactive plot
manipulate(  
{ggplot(df,aes(x=time,y=y))+  
geom_line()+  
scale_x_datetime(limits=c(x.min,x.max))},  
x.min=slider(min(time),max(time)),  
x.max=slider(min(time),max(time))
)
```

which returns `error in slider(min(time), max(time)) : min, max, and initial must all be numeric values`

If any one has any idea on how making such a plot, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `manipulate()` and `slider()` can't use dates data directly. Workaround would be to convert minimal and maximal `time` values inside the `slider()` function to numeric. Then in `scale_x_datetime()` do the opposite - convert `x.min` and `x.max` to POSIXct. Slider will display numeric values (not dates) but on the graph you will get dates on x axis.

```
manipulate(  
{ggplot(df,aes(x=time,y=y))+  
   geom_line()+  
   scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct(x.min,origin = "1970-01-01"),
                             as.POSIXct(x.max,origin = "1970-01-01")))},  
x.min=slider(as.numeric(min(df$time)),as.numeric(max(df$time))),  
x.max=slider(as.numeric(min(df$time))+2,as.numeric(max(df$time)))
)
```

Comment: It works. Will wait for the usually accepted 24h delay before voting this as an answer, but it definitively does the job. Thanks.