# Manipulating a plot with a time axis (date stamps) in R

Tags: r, time-series

The following R code creates a graph with two interactive sliders which control the range of the x-axis:

```
library(manipulate)
x = 1:100
y = 1:100*2
manipulate(plot(x, y, xlim=c(x.min,x.max)),
           x.min = slider(min(x),max(x)),
           x.max = slider(min(x),max(x)) )
```

Now I would like to do the same but the `x` values to be a time series. For example:

```
# Create a date vector length 100 in day increments from the date "2014-01-01"
x = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2014-01-01"), by=as.difftime(1, units="days"), length.out=100)
y = 1:100*2
manipulate(plot(x, y, xlim=c(x.min,x.max)),
               x.min = slider(min(x),max(x)),
               x.max = slider(min(x),max(x)) )
```

However, I get an error:

> Error in slider(min(x), max(x)) : 
>     min, max, amd initial must all be numeric values

I assume this is because `min(x)` is not numeric, its a date. But how can I do this with dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have outfitted your question based on the following SO link: [How to manipulate (using manipulate pkg) ggplot2 with time-stamped axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594795/how-to-manipulate-using-manipulate-pkg-ggplot2-with-time-stamped-axis)

Prior to using `manipulate`, it would be a good idea to combine your `x` and `y` lists into a data frame. I also switched your `POSIXct` class to `Date` since the H:M:S are just "00:00:00".

```
> df <- data.frame(x = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2014-01-01"), by=as.difftime(1, units="days"), length.out=100), y = 1:100*2)
> df$x <- as.Date(df$x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
> with(df, manipulate(plot(x, y, xlim=c(x.min, x.max), xlab = "Date", ylab = "Value"),
+            x.min = slider(as.numeric(min(x)),as.numeric(max(x)), label = "Minimum Date"),
+            x.max = slider(as.numeric(min(x)),as.numeric(max(x)), label = "Maximum Date") 
+            )
+      )
```

You will notice that your slider bar values are numeric but the final output on your graph is in a "Date" format.

Comment: Is there a way for the slides to be dates and not numerical values?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not appear `manipulate` is able to work with `Date` classes on the `slider` function. According to RStudio support, "manipulate is a pretty basic package and can only really handle what's listed in the documentation."